# How to tab to next element from code behind?

Tags: silverlight

I have a form that loads City, based on the zip code user enters when user leaves zip code input box. I need to set focus to next element after callback. There are multiple addresses and I need a way to say just get next element in tab order and set focus to it. How do I do that?

Comment: This should be handled when the user hits the tab button

Comment: @ShawnKendrot: I am not sure you understand what I was asking.

Comment: Then maybe explain your problem a little more? Providing code (xaml/c#) is always the best approach